# Alternatives to using text() to adding text to a plot

Tags: text, r, annotations, plot

This may be a naive question, but I was wondering if there's a better way than using `text()` to adding text to a plot.  Note, I'm also using `layout()` as well.  Specifically, I have a section of a plot where I would like to add some text with headings followed by regular text.

`text()` is fine it seems for simple annotations, but to get the spacing right for several lines of text seems to require a lot of manual manipulation of the `x` and `y` and `cex` parameters.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some alternative options to consider:
 - the *gplots* package has a `textplot` function to add some text output in a base graphics plot.
 - *plotrix* has a function `addtable2plot`
 - for *grid* graphics `grid.text()` is available and in *gridExtra* there is a function `grid.table()` (see, e.g., [R-Wiki](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:graphics-grid:table))

Answer (score 1):

If you're using base graphics, then `text()` is probably your best bet, and fiddling with coordinates etc is part of the game. If you want to learn a new framework, the `lattice` package is a reworking of the basic approach to plotting in R. It be installed by default so `help(package='lattice')` will get you started.

Here's a pretty good guide (pdf) to graphics in general in R, with a substantial section on `lattice`:
[download](http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~johnm/r-book/2edn/xtras/rgraphics.pdf)